# Adding menu items to the popup menu outside of an application

Tags: android, android-menu

As you can see in the picture when you click an Application pop-up menu appears. By default, this menu has 2 items (App info and Pause app). How can I add extra menu items to this popup menu?

[image]

Comment: You're looking for this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts

Comment: Exactly! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

#### I think you are searching for this

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts

In `AndriodManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
       android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

Create a new resource file: `res/xml/shortcuts.xml`

Define shortcut in the file

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <shortcut
 android:shortcutId="compose"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:icon="@drawable/compose_icon"
 android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
 android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1"
 android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_disabled_message1">
  <intent
   android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
   android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
   android:targetClass="com.example.myapplication.ComposeActivity" />
   <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
     here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
     they launch this shortcut. -->
   <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
 </shortcut>
<!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

More refrence here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

These are called App Shortcuts in Android.

For this you'll have to create an xml called `shortcuts.xml` and make few changes in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Create a file called `shortcuts.xml` in folder `res/xml-v25/`. This is because Shortcuts are supported above v25

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/your_shortcut_icon"
    android:shortcutId="custom_shortcut_id"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_short_label">
    
    // Associate action with it.
    <intent
      android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      android:targetClass="com.package.MainActivity"
      android:targetPackage="com.package"/>

  </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

And in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under the activity where MAIN and LAUNCHER intent filters are applied.

```
...
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>


        // Add this meta-data    
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/>
    </activity>
...
```

Please refer this for more details

- [Implementing Android App Shortcuts](https://medium.com/@andreworobator/implementing-android-app-shortcuts-74feb524959b#:%7E:text=App%20Shortcuts%20allow%20the%20user,to%20your%20app%27s%20primary%20actions.) by [Andrew Orobator])(https://medium.com/@andreworobator)
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts